# Use iOS 6 font for iOS 5 NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, interface-builder

I'm using Avenir, which is a font only available in iOS 6, in a project that supports iOS 5. I'm able to change the font when it's referenced in code, but I'm not sure how to change Avenir to Helvetica in the NIB files. Right now everything just defaults to system font, which is semi-acceptable except that all font sizes default to 17 regardless of their specified size in the NIB.

This is a project that has 40+ Nibs, so ideally I can find a solution that doesn't require manually editing each nib and its owner to add UILabel IBOutlets.

Thanks

Comment: Just a question: Is it worth keeping iOS5 compatibility? Very few devices run that http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/06/ahead-of-ios-7-reveal-apples-ios-6-is-on-93-of-iphones. Similarly this december probably >95% of devices will run iOS7, I suppose.

Comment: From our data, it looks like ~7% of users are on iOS5 devices. If the only issue is fixing font to gain 7% more users, I think the choice is fairly clear. :)

Comment: I know of people not changing because the YouTube app does not work in the background. They'll for ever stick to iOS5 as this functionality is messed up in all successive versions. Sure, if you don't use any new APIs and this is all you need for backward compatibility, then do it. What's sure is that new devices will come with the new OS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could purchase the font and include it in your application. That way you will have consistency with iOS5 and iOS6. I would say that is your easiest solution.

[Font](http://www.linotype.com/72/avenir-family.html)

[Include custom font in application](http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/08/12/tutorial-add-custom-font-ios-app/)

Comment: Yes that will work. You could test it by downloading a free font and including it in your project.

Comment: This seems like it would be a fairly common problem, no? Seems odd that there is no way to specify the fall back for iOS5 nibs and the only option is to purchase the font. I'm fine with falling back to Helvetica, it's just the font sizes defaulting to 17 that's the big problem.

Comment: One of the many reasons not to user Interface Builder ;-) http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder

Comment: I guess this is the best way. Sucks to add another ~1MB to the bundle size for such a minority of users.